# Gathering stats from Jitsi

Tags: javascript, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I have set up a jitsi server [from packages](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/quick-install.md) and now I'm trying to log some connection stats to a database. For example, PUT some little blobs of data about significant bitrate changes.

I feel familiar with JavaScript and somewhat familiar with WebRTC, but I don't understand the jitsi codebase that well. And it seems that the *quick* installation only gave me the minimized JavaScript files.

Where could I get the WebRTC stats of a jitsi call and where am I supposed to hook up my logging calls? What files and how should I edit?

**For future readers:** I have described how I accomplished this on the jitsi forums: https://community.jitsi.org/t/how-to-add-a-listener-for-conference-joined/42241/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're talking about client-side stats or server-side stats, but we have some support for collecting both.

On the client side, we have some logic for gathering stats but it's for an integration with a service called Callstats.io.  You could look at [this file](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/modules/statistics/CallStats.js) and the code which uses it to see if you could adapt something to your use case.

On the bridge we also gather a bunch of stats.   It's available via REST, at `serverIp:8080/colibri/debug` (though the 8080 is configurable).  You could poke around that a bit by looking at [this file](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-videobridge/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jitsi/videobridge/rest/root/colibri/debug/Debug.java).

Comment: I am looking for a client side solution. Yeah, I saw callstats and that's very similar to what I would like to do. It also seemed that the things I would need are already exposed via [this API](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/API.md). Most of my confusion is that I don't understand if I can somehow add a script to the client and retrieve the connection object? Likely no, I should probably add it in the app JS bundle, but it's compiled on my install. So is it something like clone all of the [repo](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet), add code, build, move the bundle.js?

Comment: If you're looking to gather stats without changing any of the code, I'm not sure what hooks exist, but I think you can get access to the app/lib (look at the `APP` variable.  The peer connection(s), for example, are at `APP.conference._room.p2pJingleSession.peerconnection` for p2p and `APP.conference._room.jvbJingleSession.peerconnection` for bridge connections).  If you're writing your own, most webrtc stat libs just latch onto the peer connection and pull all the stats from there (like what's in webrtc-internals).

Comment: Thanks for the directions! It didn't all click instantly for me but after some digging through the code I am gathering some events and stats.
But there's one thing that I can't solve for 5 days already - `APP.conference._room` is not available at all times. Do you know if there is any event or something when it pops into existence? Or should I just `setTimeout` and retry?

Comment: Yeah, the room is only present once things have connected.  Once it's connected it should be there consistently though, I think